# Roles & Features Installation Fails - Unable to find specified file

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, installation

I'm trying to install IIS into a new Server 2012 R2 VM but for reasons unknown the install simply fails to complete, displaying the error that it cannot find a specific file, with the error code 0x80070002.

I have tried:

- Install using all defaults
- Install specifying D:\source\sxs as the source
- Mounting a known good VM and using it as the source

All of the above have failed.

From what I can find elsewhere, people have had similar but not the same issue, and the last two attempts were both marked as "the answer" but have not helped in my case.

What can I do to find out exactly what is missing and how to point the installation wizard at it?

Comment: You might find some useful information in c:\windows\iis.log.